# julia.core.JuliaError: Exception 'MethodError: no method matching Float64(::Num)

Tags: python, julia

Attempting to call the julia ModellingToolkit in python (using JuliaCall) and obtaining the following error when attempting to define symbolic variables.

```
from julia import Main as jl

jl.eval("using ModelingToolkit")
jl.eval("using DifferentialEquations")
jl.eval("@variables t")
```

Getting the following error as a result

```
julia.core.JuliaError: Exception 'MethodError: no method matching Float64(::Num)
Closest candidates are:
  (::Type{T})(::Real, !Matched::RoundingMode) where T<:AbstractFloat at ~/Julia/julia-1.7.2/share/julia/base/rounding.jl:200
  (::Type{T})(::T) where T<:Number at ~/Julia/julia-1.7.2/share/julia/base/boot.jl:770
  (::Type{T})(!Matched::VectorizationBase.Double{T}) where T<:Union{Float16, Float32, Float64, VectorizationBase.Vec{<:Any, <:Union{Float16, Float32, Float64}}, VectorizationBase.VecUnroll{var"#s35", var"#s34", var"#s33", V} where {var"#s35", var"#s34", var"#s33"<:Union{Float16, Float32, Float64}, V<:Union{Bool, Float16, Float32, Float64, Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt8, SIMDTypes.Bit, VectorizationBase.AbstractSIMD{var"#s34", var"#s33"}}}} at ~/.julia/packages/VectorizationBase/xnzUX/src/special/double.jl:84
  ...' occurred while calling julia code:
convert(PyCall.PyObject, @variables t)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that `supertype(Num)` yields `Real` and hence PyCall tries to convert it into `Float64` before showing in Python.

A simple workaround would be to provide your own wrapper:

```
jl.eval("Float64(::Num) = NaN")
```

Now you will not be able to see object from ModelingToolkit but you can manipulate them in Python.

```
>>> jl.eval("@variables x y")
[nan, nan]
>>> jl.eval("@show simplify((x+y)^2 - (x-y)^2; expand=true)")
simplify((x + y) ^ 2 - (x - y) ^ 2; expand = true) = 4x*y
nan
```